# UAC problems with msiexec silent mode

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, installation, uac

I have a msi package which I want to install to some computers, which aren't necessary on the same domain neither network.

The way I spread the msi package it doesn't matter. We can expect that file is on some directory of local machine.

I want to run a script which installs the msi package **without user interaction**,with something similar to 

`MSIEXEC /i "setup.msi" /qn TARGETDIR="C:\my_app\"`

Although logged user is member of 'Administrators' group I've got 
`Error 1925. You don't have sufficient privileges to complete this installation for all users of the machine. Log on as administrator and then retry this installation.` message in event log after execute the msiexec command.

I've also configure UAC Settings to 'Never notify me' with same result.
**[Edited] it works after reboot...**

In split of this, I can install the software doing double click on setup.msi.

Any body knows, How I can grant permissions to setup the programs? 
As it's possible without disabling UAC.

Comment: While the logged on user is admin, what about the account that is running the installation? Are the local users executing the script/package, or are you triggering it remotely?

Comment: Basically, the logged on user having admin rights means nothing unless they are the ones triggering the installation. If they are not the ones triggering the installation, the installation is happening in a different (remote) user's session, with the rights that remote user has, which are apparently insufficient.

Comment: The user who triggers the installation is member of 'administrator' group. The installation script is executed by custom program as local user, In split of this, I've got the same result executing the msiexec command directly from cmd.

Answer (score 0):

These tests are performed in a Windows 10, you should not have problems in Windows 7, as far as I know, you must run as administrator the "Command Prompt", even if you are an administrator or in a Group of Administrators.

Try "search", simply press the "Windows" key and type ***cmd***, now press right button on the result and choose **"Run as Administrator"**,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5Hxr.png)
and then use Msiexec:

```
start /wait Msiexec /p "AcrobatUpd952_all_incr.msp" /qn /norestart
```

Check it out the reason why I´m here: the source ***Acro.bat***

[Acrobat 9 Update](https://oitibs.com/adobe-acrobat-9-0-offline-update/)